# Zsh git email in prompt not refreshing

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, quoting

### Problem

I have oh my zsh installed on mac OS catalina and using iTerm2 as terminal. I am using `robbyrussell.zsh-theme` theme and have modified it to print git email in the prompt (More info [here](https://gist.github.com/aesopwolf/2f899068f1fb85976265ad21ffb59858)). I have modified `robbyrussell.zsh-theme` to this:

```
PROMPT="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"
PROMPT+=' %{$fg[cyan]%}%~%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[blue]%}$(git_current_user_email)["
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%} "
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}] %{$fg[yellow]%}✗"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[blue]%}] %{$fg[green]%}✔"
```

When I move to a git directory it is not picking up user email from local `.git/config` or from global `~/.git/config`.

### Research done:

I went through multiple stackoverflow and other articles and tried bunch of stuff but with no success.

The approach that worked for me was creating aliases to switch between two email addresses:

```
home='git config user.email "<homeemail>" && source ~/.zshrc'
work='git config user.email "<workemail>" && source ~/.zshrc'
```

But I have to execute these commands all the time to make prompt pick up the email even if it is set in local git config.

Can someone help regarding what needs to be done to zsh prompt to read git user email directly when we cd to a repo?

Comment: I've just realized that my answer did not really work when not in a git repository. I've updated it.

Comment: Your answer worked fine for me even when not in git repo. But just needed a small formatting change to keep `[` in `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX` and not bring it to `PROMPT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[blue]%}$(git_current_user_email)["` uses double quotes, which causes `$(git_current_user_email)` to be evaluated only once when `robbyrussell.zsh-theme` gets sourced, not for every prompt.

You can confirm this by running `echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX"`, which should now contain the email address, instead of a literal `$(git_current_user_email)`.

Unfortunately you can't use single quotes (which do not evaluate substitutions) either here. As then you'll see a literal `$(git_current_user_email)` in your prompt, as the `git_prompt_info` function (which uses `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX` internally) does not evaluate it.

**What you can do however** is to put `$(git_current_user_email)` directly into `PROMPT`, which does get evaluated on each new prompt.

But we'll need to disable it ourselves when not in a git repository and can't rely on the git plugin.

Something like this:

```sh
PROMPT="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"
PROMPT+=' %{$fg[cyan]%}%~%{$reset_color%} $(my_git_prompt_prefix)$(git_prompt_info)'

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX=""
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%} "
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}] %{$fg[yellow]%}✗"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[blue]%}] %{$fg[green]%}✔"

function my_git_prompt_prefix() {
  # Based on: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/d646884add277d134235a9b18ab755388d6e0d8d/lib/git.zsh#L15-L23
  # If we are on a folder not tracked by git, get out.
  # Otherwise, check for hide-info at global and local repository level
  if ! __git_prompt_git rev-parse --git-dir &> /dev/null \
     || [[ "$(__git_prompt_git config --get oh-my-zsh.hide-info 2>/dev/null)" == 1 ]]; then
    return 0
  fi

  local ref
  ref=$(__git_prompt_git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2> /dev/null) \
  || ref=$(__git_prompt_git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null) \
  || return 0

  # The actual git prompt prefix
  echo "%{$fg[blue]%}$(git_current_user_email)["
}
```

(Also notice how `PROMPT` has single quotes instead of double quotes).

More details on the different quoting styles and substitutions can be found here: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Your earlier solution worked fine but needed a small tweak for case when not in git repo. The solution that I am posting below worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As per solution suggested by @mihi with a small tweak, this worked fine for me:

```
PROMPT="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"
PROMPT+=' %{$fg[cyan]%}%~%{$reset_color%} %{$fg[blue]%}$(git_current_user_email)$(git_prompt_info)'
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="["
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%} "
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}] %{$fg[yellow]%}✗"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[blue]%}] %{$fg[green]%}✔"
```